# Does this code qualify to be a block cipher

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, block-cipher

Ok, before you guys reprimand me : I am aware this is a horrible code and super weak cipher. I just trying to find out if the following qualifies to be a block cipher ( even a very rudimentary and weak one )

```
int main(){
   int mac = 123;
   int key = 789;

   int enc = mac^key;
   printf("encrypted text  =  %d\n",enc);

   int plain = enc^key;
   printf("decrypted text = %d\n",plain);

   return 0;
}
```

Here is the output :

```
encrypted text  =  878
decrypted text = 123
```

Comment: If the key consist of perfectly random bits and is not reused, then this is actually an implementation of a [one time pad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad), not a block cipher.

Comment: If this were an algorithm rather than an example it might be a block cipher. But it might just as well be a one time pad, or something else.

Comment: how about if i were split each digit of the mac and and then do the same as above. It would be the same output, However now I am breaking them message into "blocks" of single digits and doing XOR and then recombining them at the other end

Comment: IMO it is a block cipher. A really bad one, but one none the less.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are certain generalities that have to be followed in order to create a block cipher. The code you have shown **is technically not a block cipher**. Generalities such as:

- In a block cipher **the message is broken into blocks**, **each** of which is then **encrypted** (ie like a substitution on very big characters - 64-bits or more)
- A block cipher **consists of two paired algorithms**, one for **encryption, E, and the other for decryption, E−1**. Both algorithms accept two inputs: an **input block of size n bits** and a **key of size k bits**, yielding an n-bit output block. For any one fixed key, **decryption is the inverse function of encryption**.

Encryption in block cipher mode (ECB, CBC) uses a specific flow:

- The first thing that a block cipher must do is **break the plaintext into equally-sized blocks**, usually 8 bytes, for instance the ASCII encoding of `imablock`.
- Encrypt the plaintext using a cipher.
- Decrypt the message.

The choice of cipher is implementation dependent.

The point being, **while you may have followed the flow for Encryption-Decryption, you program doesn't satisfy the generalities of block ciphers.** You need to break your message into **blocks** to implement a [symmetric cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_cipher).

What **you have implemented**, is **simple encryption and not a block cipher**.

There are so many references:

- [Block Ciphers](http://library.thinkquest.org/27993/crypto/dig/block1.shtml) - Neat and clean explanation for block ciphers and related operations.
- [Wikipedia - Block Ciphers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) - Obvious reference.. :P

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: thanks a lot .. this settles an argument I have been having with my friend over this code

Comment: Hahaha. Friends huh.. :P .. Glad to help. :)

Comment: +1 removed some code blocks that were used for highlighting though, and added some minor clarifications. To be precise, a block cipher can only encrypt/decrypt a single block, the division in blocks of plain text is purely part of a [block cipher mode of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).